# how to read secrets in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

Below is the github action

```yaml
name: Build image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.2.0
  with:
    build-args: 
    secrets: |
        "github_token=${{ inputs.token }}"
        "uname=${{ github.actor }}"
        "Mysecret=SecretValue"
```

in the Docker file

```bash
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_token \
    cat /run/secrets/github_token

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_actor \
    cat /run/secrets/github_actor

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_actor \
    varu=$(cat /run/secrets/github_actor)

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_token \
    var=$(cat /run/secrets/github_token) 

RUN echo $var
```

I'm not able to consume the secrets, those are printing but not able to assing the secret to a variables for use in next statement.

If I want to get Mysecret value to a variable in docker file how do I get it?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to inline secrets inside of docker images. Sure you can have private image registries and images can contain non-public stuff, but secrets are something local. If you're not shipping your image anywhere and only building and using it locally, why not assign your secret to the containers running with this image, maybe using a compose file? If that is not an option, can you explain the general setup?

Comment: the whole point of these secrets is that they are only available in the instruction they are mounted.  You can write them to a file and stuff but that defeats the purpose since they will end up in layer cache. Mount the secret where you actually need it.